# Length spaces in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: metric-spaces, optimal-transport

I am presently reading the following notes: [https://people.math.ethz.ch/~afigalli/lecture-notes-pdf/Optimal-Transport-and-Curvature.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Eafigalli/lecture-notes-pdf/Optimal-Transport-and-Curvature.pdf) and I could not fully understand the second part of Example 1.1, i.e:

If $X$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ then $(X, d)$ is a length space if and only if X is convex.

Thanks for helping me on this point.

Comment: Hint: The idea is to show that if $\gamma_n$ are continuous paths in $X$ from $x$ to $y$ with $l(\gamma_n) \to \|x-y\|$, then, in some sense, $(\gamma_n)$ converges to the straight segment $[x,y]$. The fact $X$ is closed will show that $[x,y] \subset X$.

Comment: Yes, thanks that helps in clearing things!